# sorting settings not displayed

Tags: magento2

I have Magento 2.4.4 but the sorting settings are not displayed!
I don't see that in the screenshot...[image]

Comment: Above is for paid edition not for free edition

Answer (score 0):

The sort order feature in your screenshot is exclusive to Adobe Commerce (paid edition) and not available for Magento Open Source.